# Why would a line's SHA in a git blame view have a leading caret (^)?

Tags: git

I'm not sure if this behavior is bizarre, but here's what's happening: it seems if I run `git blame` on a file, any lines in that file that are from the initial commit have a SHA with a leading caret (`^`), like this

```
^bb65026 (Brian Danielak 2012-10-27 19:11:54 -0700 1) hello, world!
bbcd4a96 (Brian Danielak 2012-10-27 19:11:54 -0700 2) hello again!
```

### Steps to Reproduce

From a terminal prompt:

```
mkdir newProject
cd newProject
git init
echo 'hello, world!' >> testFile.txt
git add testFile.txt
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git blame testFile.txt
```

Then verify your blame output has a leading caret, as mine did (though your SHA likely won't match)

```
^bb65026 (Brian Danielak 2012-10-27 19:11:54 -0700 1) hello, world!
```

As a test, you can try adding a second line to a file and re-committing, to see that only the hash of the first line contains a leading caret

```
echo 'hello again!' >> testFile.txt
git add testFile.txt
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git blame testFile.txt
```

My blame output now looks like this:

```
^bb65026 (Brian Danielak 2012-10-27 19:11:54 -0700 1) hello, world!
bbcd4a96 (Brian Danielak 2012-10-27 19:11:54 -0700 2) hello again!
```

Can anyone explain why this happens, and whether I should have expected it? Does it only happen when a line comes from the first commit in a repo? If so, why?

Comment: btw - you can still do: git log bb65026 -p etc. (less the caret) and see those details.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The docs for [git blame](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) actually do mention the caret as being used for a "boundary commit", which it looks like they're defining something like "the oldest commit in this blame range" -- in your case it's the project's initial commit, but with some different options you may have only blamed up to commits from 3 weeks ago.

Comment: Could the man page describe this better? Is there a better place for the description of the 'caret' prefix?

Comment: @PhilipOakley Yes, the man page could definitely stand to be more clear about a boundary commit.  A cursory search of 'git "boundary commit" on Google doesn't turn up anything more clear from the git man pages.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue suddenly in a very old repository and was confused by it.

The problem ended up being that I had somehow gotten a shallow clone at some point. A simple `git fetch --unshallow` remedied it.